# Grouping and rollup in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have problem with my code.
this is example data looks like

```
var data = [
{
"office": "George Town Office",
"city_name": "George Town",
"total_employee": 2100,
},
{
"office": "George Town Working Space",
"city_name": "George Town",
"total_employee": 100,
},
{
"office": "Renasti KL Office",
"city_name": "Kuala Lumpur",
"total_employee": 1900,
}
]
```

and I have grouping it with the key (city_name) and i have problem with the rollup if i need to calculate total_employee. This is the code

```
var nested_data =  d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {  return d.city_name; })
    //error undefined .rollup(function(v, i) { return v.total_employee; })
    .entries(da);
```

and example of the console result like tis

```
0:
key: "George Town"
values: Array(8)
0: {city_name: "George Town", office: "George Town Office", total_employee: 2100, …}
1: {city_name: "George Town", office: "George Town Office Working Space", total_employee: 100, …}
```

And my problem is how to calculate the total_employee in same key?
expected result

```
key: "George Town"
values: total_employee: 2200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `rollup` method...

```
.rollup(function(v, i) { return v.total_employee; })
```

... `v` is an array of objects, not a single object. Therefore, you should threat it as an array, for instance using `d3.sum`:

```
.rollup(function(v) {
    return d3.sum(v, function(e) {
        return e.total_employee;
    })
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
    "office": "George Town Office",
    "city_name": "George Town",
    "total_employee": 2100,
  },
  {
    "office": "George Town Working Space",
    "city_name": "George Town",
    "total_employee": 100,
  },
  {
    "office": "Renasti KL Office",
    "city_name": "Kuala Lumpur",
    "total_employee": 1900,
  }
]

var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.city_name;
  })
  .rollup(function(v) {
    return d3.sum(v, function(e) {
      return e.total_employee;
    })
  })
  .entries(data);

console.log(nested_data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```